# If/ else if statement in keil only evaluating to else if

Tags: c, microcontroller, 8051, keil

I am writing code for an 8051 micro controller simulated on a development board and I am trying to make a clock simulated on an LCD. I have 2 functions for an alarm and a stopwatch that I want to be activated by 2 separate switches but the code doesn't seem to acknowledge either switch being pressed and just runs the main clock code in the second else if. This is the code:

```
#include <REG51.H>

//Define which microcontroller port connects to the LCD data pins
#define LCD_DATA_PORT P2

//LCD commands
#define FunctionSet 0x3B
#define DisplayOn 0x0E
#define EntryModeSet 0x06
#define ClearScreen 0x01
#define SecondLine 0xC0

//function prototypes
void lcd_data_write(unsigned char display_data) ;
void lcd_command_write(unsigned char display_data);
void delayX1msec(unsigned int no_loops);
void init_lcd();

//Port pin definitions
sbit minute_button = P3^3;
sbit hour_button = P3^2;
sbit twentyfour_button = P3^1;
sbit alarm_button = P3^0;
sbit stopwatch_button = P1^0;

sbit alarm_led = P3^7;
//port pin functions for lcd
sbit EN = P3^5;
sbit RS = P3^4;
sbit RW = P3^6;

//function prototype
void delayX1msec(unsigned int no_loops);
void alarmfunction();
void stopwatchfunction();

//time variables
unsigned char seconds=0, minutes=0, hours=0, hours1=0;
unsigned char alarm_seconds=0, alarm_minutes=0, alarm_hours=0;
unsigned char stopwatch_miliseconds=0, stopwatch_seconds=0, stopwatch_minutes=0;

void main()
{
    IT0=1;
    IT1=1;
    IE=0x85;
    init_lcd(); //initialise the LCD
    while(1)
    {
        delayX1msec(950); //1 second delay
        if(stopwatch_button==1 && alarm_button==0)
        {
            stopwatchfunction();
        }
        else if(alarm_button == 1 && stopwatch_button==0)
        {
            alarmfunction();
        }
        else if(alarm_button == 0 && stopwatch_button == 0)
        {
            if(seconds<59)
            {
                seconds++; //increment seconds          
            }
            else
            {
                seconds = 0;
                if(minutes<59) //increment minutes every 60 seconds
                {
                    minutes++;
                }
                else
                {
                    if(hours<23) //increment hour every 60 minutes
                    {
                        hours++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        hours = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
            lcd_command_write(ClearScreen); //clear the screen before every input
            if(twentyfour_button == 1)
            {
                lcd_data_write('2');
                lcd_data_write('4');
                lcd_data_write('h');
                lcd_data_write(' ');
                lcd_data_write(hours/10 + 0x30); //hours tens
                lcd_data_write(hours%10 + 0x30); //hours units
                lcd_data_write(':');
                lcd_data_write(minutes/10 + 0x30); //minutes tens
                lcd_data_write(minutes%10 + 0x30); //minutes units
                lcd_data_write(':');
                lcd_data_write(seconds/10 + 0x30); //minutes tens
                lcd_data_write(seconds%10 + 0x30); //minutes units
            }
            else
            {
                lcd_data_write('1');
                lcd_data_write('2');
                lcd_data_write('h');
                lcd_data_write(' ');
                if(hours > 11)
                {
                    hours1 = hours - 12;
                    lcd_data_write(hours1/10 + 0x30); //hours tens
                    lcd_data_write(hours1%10 + 0x30); //hours units
                }
                else
                {
                    lcd_data_write(hours/10 + 0x30); //hours tens
                    lcd_data_write(hours%10 + 0x30); //hours units
                }
                lcd_data_write(':');
                lcd_data_write(minutes/10 + 0x30); //minutes tens
                lcd_data_write(minutes%10 + 0x30); //minutes units
                lcd_data_write(':');
                lcd_data_write(seconds/10 + 0x30); //minutes tens
                lcd_data_write(seconds%10 + 0x30); //minutes units
                if(hours > 11)
                {
                    lcd_data_write(' ');
                    lcd_data_write('P');
                    lcd_data_write('M');
                }
                else
                {
                    lcd_data_write(' ');
                    lcd_data_write('A');
                    lcd_data_write('M');
                }
            }
        if(alarm_hours == hours && alarm_minutes == minutes)
        {
            alarm_led = ~alarm_led;
        }
    }
 }
}

void stopwatchfunction()
{
        delayX1msec(1);             //1 second delay
        if(stopwatch_miliseconds<59)
        {
            stopwatch_miliseconds++; //increment seconds            
        }
        else
        {
            stopwatch_miliseconds = 0;
            if(stopwatch_seconds<59) //increment minutes every 60 seconds
            {
                stopwatch_seconds++;
            }
            else
            {
                stopwatch_seconds = 0;
                if(stopwatch_minutes<11) //increment hour every 60 minutes
                {
                    stopwatch_minutes++;
                }
                else
                {
                    stopwatch_minutes = 0;
                }
            }
        }
        lcd_command_write(ClearScreen); //clear the screen before every input
        lcd_data_write(stopwatch_minutes/10 + 0x30); //hours tens
        lcd_data_write(stopwatch_minutes%10 + 0x30); //hours units
        lcd_data_write(':');
        lcd_data_write(stopwatch_seconds/10 + 0x30); //minutes tens
        lcd_data_write(stopwatch_seconds%10 + 0x30); //minutes units
        lcd_data_write(':');
        lcd_data_write(stopwatch_miliseconds/10 + 0x30); //minutes tens
        lcd_data_write(stopwatch_miliseconds%10 + 0x30); //minutes units
}

void alarmfunction()
{
        lcd_command_write(ClearScreen); //clear the screen before every input
        lcd_data_write(alarm_hours/10 + 0x30); //hours tens
        lcd_data_write(alarm_hours%10 + 0x30); //hours units
        lcd_data_write(':');
        lcd_data_write(alarm_minutes/10 + 0x30); //minutes tens
        lcd_data_write(alarm_minutes%10 + 0x30); //minutes units
}

void minute_isr() interrupt 2
{
             //if the minute button is pressed increment minutes
    if(alarm_button == 0)
    {
        if(minutes<59)
            minutes++;
        else
        {
            minutes = 0;
            hours++;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if(alarm_minutes<59)
            alarm_minutes++;
        else
        {
            alarm_minutes = 0;
            alarm_hours++;
        }
    }
}


void hour_isr() interrupt 0
{
            //if the hour button is pressed increment hours
    if(alarm_button == 0)
    {
            if(hours<23)
                hours++;
            else
                hours = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        if(alarm_hours<23)
            alarm_hours++;
        else
            alarm_hours = 0;
    }
}
//**************************************************************************
//function to generate a delay of x * 1msec
//e.g. delay(50); generates a 50msec delay
//Assumes a 12MHz crystal oscillator
void delayX1msec(unsigned int no_loops)
{
    unsigned int x;
    TR0 = 0;
    TF0 = 0;
    TMOD = 0x01;
    TH0 = 0xFC;
    TL0 = 0x18;
    TR0 = 1;
    for(x=0;x<no_loops;x++)
    {
        while(!TF0);
        TF0 = 0;
        TH0 = 0xFC;
        TL0 = 0x18;
    }
    TR0 = 0;
}

//function to initialise the LCD display
void init_lcd()
{
    lcd_command_write(FunctionSet);
    lcd_command_write(DisplayOn);
    lcd_command_write(EntryModeSet);
    lcd_command_write(ClearScreen);
}
//**************************************************************************
// Function to write a display character to the LCD
void lcd_data_write(unsigned char display_data)
{
    RW = 0;
    RS = 1;
    EN = 1;
    LCD_DATA_PORT = display_data;
    EN = 0;
    delayX1msec(5);     //delay to allow write operation to complete
}
//**************************************************************************
// Function to write a command to the LCD
void lcd_command_write(unsigned char command)
{
    RW = 0;
    RS = 0;
    EN = 1;
    LCD_DATA_PORT = command;
    EN = 0;
    delayX1msec(5);     //delay to allow write operation to complete
}
```

Comment: I think the way to debug this would be to make sure that stopwatch_button and alarm_button are doing what they should do when you press the button. There are many things that could be wrong here. First, remove everything else in the while loop and make else-if loop simple and shorter, so that the while loop can loop faster (compare to how it is right now), and then press a switch to see if alarm_button/stopwatch_button ever gets one. It might be that when you press the switch, it is missed because it is already inside second else if loop. since these are not interrupt triggered, timings matter

Comment: Or it could be that your sbit is being optimized away. Is it changed by an interrupt? If it is, please use volatile.

Comment: You're testing twentyfour_button for == 1. Should you be testing it for != 0? Or does the sbit declaration do the shifting for you?